# how do I check decimal.is_nan() for all values in array?

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, nan

Suppose I have my array like this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
array = [Decimal(np.nan), Decimal(np.nan), Decimal(0.231411)]
```

I know that if the types are `float`, I can check if all the values are `nan` or not
, as:

```
np.isnan(array).all()
```

Is there a way for type `Decimal`?

The solution would be better without iteration.

Comment: What is `Decimal`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Yatin - It’s the `Decimal` class from the `decimal` library.  It’s a builtin.  `from decimal import Decimal`  The example is reproducible.

Comment: Granted, it’s an iteration, but: `all([i.is_nan() for i in array])`.

Comment: you have a list, why are you using `numpy` with a list of `Decimal` objects? `Decimal` means you have `dtype=object`, so iteration is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NumPy's [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to avoid iteration.

```py
In [40]: from decimal import Decimal

In [41]: import numpy as np

In [42]: nums = [Decimal(np.nan), Decimal(np.nan), Decimal(0.231411)]

In [43]: nums
Out[43]: 
[Decimal('NaN'),
 Decimal('NaN'),
 Decimal('0.2314110000000000055830895462349872104823589324951171875')]

In [44]: np.all(np.vectorize(lambda x: x.is_nan())(np.asarray(nums)))
Out[44]: False

In [45]: np.all(np.vectorize(lambda x: x.is_nan())(np.asarray(nums[:-1])))
Out[45]: True
```

In the snippet above `nums` is a list of instances of class `Decimal`. Notice that you need to convert that list into a NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above, I realise it’s an iteration. The reason is that `np.isnan` does not support `Decimal` as an input type; therefore, I don’t believe this can be done via broadcasting, without converting the datatype - which means a potential precision loss, which is a reason to use a `Decimal` type.

Additionally, as commented by @juanpa.arrivillaga, as the `Decimal` objects are in a `list`, iteration is the only way.  Numpy is not necessary in this operation.

One method is:

```
all([i.is_nan() for i in array])
```